# MySql how can i get specific value before specific character in where clause of specific column

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to get specific value before specific character from specific column.

For example  ..[image]

In town column i want only string value before `-` character , I mean only need `ABBEYARD`  from town column.

I have used following query but not work.

```
SELECT * FROM `locations` WHERE town = SUBSTRING_INDEX('ABBOTSFORD','-',1)
```

**Note:** I only need in `WHERE` Clouse.

Comment: Please make an [edit] to clarify your question. Do your want to search the `town` column for a town with a particular name? Or do you want to SELECT just the town names, with the ` - nnnn` part of the value omitted?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(town, '-', 1) = 'ABBOTSFORD'
```

However, I would recommend writing this as:

```
WHERE town LIKE 'ABBOTSFORD-%'
```

This can actually take advantage of an index.

Also, it looks like your data might have spaces around the `'-'`.  If so, those should be in the comparison strings as well.

```
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(town, ' - ', 1) = 'ABBOTSFORD'
WHERE town LIKE 'ABBOTSFORD -%'
```

You can repeat `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` in the `SELECT` to 
get only the town or the number that follows.

Comment: I have tried as per your suggestion but still return with number  not geting only ABBOTSFORD  it's return ABBOTSFORD - 3067

Comment: @SamirSheikh, what do you mean with return in "return with number", you said you only need this in the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the town names because in the column `town` they are concatenated with the `postcode`, then you need to modify the `select` and not the `where` part:

```
SELECT id, TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(town, '-', 1)) townname, postcode, state FROM locations
```

and maybe add this `where` part:

```
WHERE TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(town, '-', 1)) = 'ABBOTSFORD'
```